# What is a shop that sells phones, tablets and computers called?

Tags: word-choice

Can I call it an [electronics shop](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBD_enIT855IT855&ei=s7ghXdHWGcyr1fAPh4G02AQ&q=%22electronics%20shop%22&oq=%22electronics%20shop%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i67j0i7i30l9.14880.19488..20272...0.0..0.95.172.2......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0.MjdatyhCkg8)?

What would it be called in the US or in the UK? What would a native English speaker call it?

Comment: An electronics shop or store should suffice. You could call it a computer or smartphone store as well.

Comment: An *Apple store* refers to a specific brand but is widely recognized as exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: I think you mean to ask about a shop that *only* sells those things. There are a huge number of stores (and words for stores) that sell those things in addition to a wide range of other stock.

Comment: Jasson Bassford: tell me please what you would call such a store

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An electronic store would work. Technology/Tech shop might work in some regions. Stores selling technological devices of a specific company can be called by the name of the company followed by the word 'store'. For example, An Apple Store, A Samsung store. Hope this helps!